# Process in Windows uses my whole cpu, how to identify

Tags: windows, cpu

For a while now my windows machine goes into full load using all of my cores (i7-930) for a few seconds, this is quite annoying since it induces fps drops in gaming and general laginess when working.

Is there a log or a tool that can log the cpu usage ? When I try the task manager it just never shows a single process at 100% even when it says 100% cpu usage.

Anyone an idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) (A tool like Task Manager but way more powerful).

You can see a list of all the process and their CPU usage, and other useful information (CPU time, CPU history, etc...) for diagnosing many issues with your computer.

[image: Process Explorer main window]

**Note:** As Tom Wijsman pointed out, you must run as with admin privileges to see the processes from all users

[image: Run Process Explorer with admin privileges]

Comment: **Attention:** Run as administrator so you can get to see the CPU of all processes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this process is not running under your user. Select "all users" in your "processes" pane. Depending on your OS version there is a checkbox or button labelt unambiguously.